# Android screen wakeup only works with full_wake_lock

Tags: android, wakelock, powermanager

I have a service that listens to push notifications and creates an activity.  Everything works well except when the device's screen is off.  The desired behavior is that a notification would wake the screen up to the **locked state homescreen** and display the notification.

I am only able to create this behavior with:

```
mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |
                           PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                           PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE,
                           WAKELOCK_KEY);
```

However, I see that Android has deprecated `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` in favor of FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON.  However, I have tried this in the activity that is called from the background service:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON |
                     WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

And my logs show that this activity is being created but the screen still does not display this activity.  If I press the power button, the display shows the activity immediately proving that it was created.  Here is a summary of some of the things I have tried:

1. FULL_WAKE_LOCK (works but is deprecated)
2. WindowManager - FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON, FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON (doesn't work)
3. Google WakefulBroadCastReceiver (doesn't work)

Are there any alternatives to `FULL_WAKE_LOCK`?

Answer (score 0):

Waking up (SCREEN_ON) device from service works with

`newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK |  PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP | ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "MyTag").`

**Tested on Android 4.1, 4.4, 5.0**

In my app i am waking up the device via the `AlarmManager` and registering a broadcast event.
Be sure to acquire wakelock in the `WakefulBroadCastReceiver` **before** starting service and release the lock **not** in the same callstack in the service as doing this will reside the device in SCREEN_OFF.

Comment: FULL_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated.

Answer (score -1):

This is what Android Clock do in the onCreate method:

```
    final Window win = getWindow();
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    // Turn on the screen unless we are being launched from the AlarmAlert
    // subclass as a result of the screen turning off.
    win.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

Are you using the first set of flags?

Edit: I've just tested it and it works.